# How to Send New Messages from Azure IoT Edge Module Python

Tags: python, azure, module, azure-iot-edge

It seems there is not very much support for what I am trying to do, but it is supposed to be possible since it is demonstrated in [temperature sensor and sensor filter tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-python-module). However, there are no examples for the actual message creation from an edge module in python. That tutorial only shows forwarding messages. There are examples of sending from a device, but devices use a different class than edge modules. From the filter example and from a couple of device examples I have pieced together the following:

```
# Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE file in the project root for
# full license information.

import random
import time
import sys
import iothub_client
from iothub_client import IoTHubModuleClient, IoTHubClientError, IoTHubTransportProvider
from iothub_client import IoTHubMessage, IoTHubMessageDispositionResult, IoTHubError

# messageTimeout - the maximum time in milliseconds until a message times out.
# The timeout period starts at IoTHubModuleClient.send_event_async.
# By default, messages do not expire.
MESSAGE_TIMEOUT = 10000

# global counters
RECEIVE_CALLBACKS = 0
SEND_CALLBACKS = 0

# Choose HTTP, AMQP or MQTT as transport protocol.  Currently only MQTT is supported.
PROTOCOL = IoTHubTransportProvider.MQTT

# Callback received when the message that we're forwarding is processed.
def send_confirmation_callback(message, result, user_context):
    global SEND_CALLBACKS
    print ( "Confirmation[%d] received for message with result = %s" % (user_context, result) )
    map_properties = message.properties()
    key_value_pair = map_properties.get_internals()
    print ( "    Properties: %s" % key_value_pair )
    SEND_CALLBACKS += 1
    print ( "    Total calls confirmed: %d" % SEND_CALLBACKS )


# receive_message_callback is invoked when an incoming message arrives on the specified 
# input queue (in the case of this sample, "input1").  Because this is a filter module, 
# we will forward this message onto the "output1" queue.
def receive_message_callback(message, hubManager):
    global RECEIVE_CALLBACKS
    message_buffer = message.get_bytearray()
    size = len(message_buffer)
    print ( "    Data: <<<%s>>> & Size=%d" % (message_buffer[:size].decode('utf-8'), size) )
    map_properties = message.properties()
    key_value_pair = map_properties.get_internals()
    print ( "    Properties: %s" % key_value_pair )
    RECEIVE_CALLBACKS += 1
    print ( "    Total calls received: %d" % RECEIVE_CALLBACKS )
    hubManager.forward_event_to_output("output1", message, 0)
    return IoTHubMessageDispositionResult.ACCEPTED


def construct_message(message_body, topic):
    try:
        msg_txt_formatted = message_body
        message = IoTHubMessage(msg_txt_formatted)

        # Add a custom application property to the message.
        # An IoT hub can filter on these properties without access to the message body.
        prop_map = message.properties()
        prop_map.add("topic", topic)

        # TODO Use logging
        # Send the message.
        print( "Sending message: %s" % message.get_string() )

    except IoTHubError as iothub_error:
        print ( "Unexpected error %s from IoTHub" % iothub_error )
        return

    return message


class HubManager(object):

    def __init__(
            self,
            protocol=IoTHubTransportProvider.MQTT):
        self.client_protocol = protocol
        self.client = IoTHubModuleClient()
        self.client.create_from_environment(protocol)

        # set the time until a message times out
        self.client.set_option("messageTimeout", MESSAGE_TIMEOUT)

        # sets the callback when a message arrives on "input1" queue.  Messages sent to 
        # other inputs or to the default will be silently discarded.
        self.client.set_message_callback("input1", receive_message_callback, self)

    # Forwards the message received onto the next stage in the process.
    def forward_event_to_output(self, outputQueueName, event, send_context):
        self.client.send_event_async(
            outputQueueName, event, send_confirmation_callback, send_context)

    def send_message(self, message):
        # No callback
        # TODO what is the third arg?
        self.client.send_event_async(
            "output1", message, send_confirmation_callback, 0)
            self.client.send_message()

    def mypublish(self, topic, msg):
        message = construct_message(msg, topic)
        self.send_message(message)
        print('publishing %s', msg)

def main(protocol):
    try:
        print ( "\nPython %s\n" % sys.version )
        print ( "IoT Hub Client for Python" )

        hub_manager = HubManager(protocol)

        print ( "Starting the IoT Hub Python sample using protocol %s..." % hub_manager.client_protocol )
        print ( "The sample is now waiting for messages and will indefinitely.  Press Ctrl-C to exit. ")

        while True:
            hub_manager.mypublish('testtopic', 'hello world this is a module')
            time.sleep(1)

    except IoTHubError as iothub_error:
        print ( "Unexpected error %s from IoTHub" % iothub_error )
        return
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ( "IoTHubModuleClient sample stopped" )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(PROTOCOL)
```

When I build and deploy this it executes on the edge device without errors and in the log, the callback reports that the messages are sent ok. However, no messages come through when I attempt to monitor D2C messages.

Comment: What routes do you have setup in your deployment? Do you have one that forwards messages from `output1` on your module to the `$upstream` endpoint?

Comment: @Raj Yes, my routes are like so
`"routes": {
          "SendingModuleToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/SendingModule/outputs/output1 INTO $upstream"
        },`

Comment: Seems the same problem I answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61497052/1665473

Answer (score 1):

I used this to create and send a message from a JSON dict.

```
new_message = json.dumps(json_obj)
new_message = IoTHubMessage(new_message)
hubManager.forward_event_to_output("output1", new_message, 0)
```

You can send anything you need, even strings or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

To narrow down the issue, you can install the azureiotedge-simulated-temperature-sensor module published by Microsoft to see whether the issue relative to the Edge environment issue or coding.

I also wrote a sample Python code module based on the Python Module templates which works well for me, you can refer the code below:

```
# Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE file in the project root for
# full license information.

import random
import time
import sys
import iothub_client
from iothub_client import IoTHubModuleClient, IoTHubClientError, IoTHubTransportProvider
from iothub_client import IoTHubMessage, IoTHubMessageDispositionResult, IoTHubError

# messageTimeout - the maximum time in milliseconds until a message times out.
# The timeout period starts at IoTHubModuleClient.send_event_async.
# By default, messages do not expire.
MESSAGE_TIMEOUT = 10000

# global counters
RECEIVE_CALLBACKS = 0
SEND_CALLBACKS = 0

# Choose HTTP, AMQP or MQTT as transport protocol.  Currently only MQTT is supported.
PROTOCOL = IoTHubTransportProvider.MQTT

# Callback received when the message that we're forwarding is processed.
def send_confirmation_callback(message, result, user_context):
    global SEND_CALLBACKS
    print ( "Confirmation[%d] received for message with result = %s" % (user_context, result) )
    map_properties = message.properties()
    key_value_pair = map_properties.get_internals()
    print ( "    Properties: %s" % key_value_pair )
    SEND_CALLBACKS += 1
    print ( "    Total calls confirmed: %d" % SEND_CALLBACKS )


# receive_message_callback is invoked when an incoming message arrives on the specified 
# input queue (in the case of this sample, "input1").  Because this is a filter module, 
# we will forward this message onto the "output1" queue.
def receive_message_callback(message, hubManager):
    global RECEIVE_CALLBACKS
    message_buffer = message.get_bytearray()
    size = len(message_buffer)
    print ( "    Data: <<<%s>>> & Size=%d" % (message_buffer[:size].decode('utf-8'), size) )
    map_properties = message.properties()
    key_value_pair = map_properties.get_internals()
    print ( "    Properties: %s" % key_value_pair )
    RECEIVE_CALLBACKS += 1
    print ( "    Total calls received: %d" % RECEIVE_CALLBACKS )
    hubManager.forward_event_to_output("output1", message, 0)
    return IoTHubMessageDispositionResult.ACCEPTED


class HubManager(object):

    def __init__(
            self,
            protocol=IoTHubTransportProvider.MQTT):
        self.client_protocol = protocol
        self.client = IoTHubModuleClient()
        self.client.create_from_environment(protocol)

        # set the time until a message times out
        self.client.set_option("messageTimeout", MESSAGE_TIMEOUT)

        # sets the callback when a message arrives on "input1" queue.  Messages sent to 
        # other inputs or to the default will be silently discarded.
        self.client.set_message_callback("input1", receive_message_callback, self)

    # Forwards the message received onto the next stage in the process.
    def forward_event_to_output(self, outputQueueName, event, send_context):
        self.client.send_event_async(
            outputQueueName, event, send_confirmation_callback, send_context)

    def SendSimulationData(self, msg):
        print"sending message..."
        message=IoTHubMessage(msg)
        self.client.send_event_async(
            "output1", message, send_confirmation_callback, 0)
        print"finished sending message..."



def main(protocol):
    try:
        print ( "\nPython %s\n" % sys.version )
        print ( "IoT Hub Client for Python" )

        hub_manager = HubManager(protocol)

        print ( "Starting the IoT Hub Python sample using protocol %s..." % hub_manager.client_protocol )
        print ( "The sample is now waiting for messages and will indefinitely.  Press Ctrl-C to exit. ")

        while True:
            hub_manager.SendSimulationData("test msg")
            time.sleep(1)

    except IoTHubError as iothub_error:
        print ( "Unexpected error %s from IoTHub" % iothub_error )
        return
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ( "IoTHubModuleClient sample stopped" )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(PROTOCOL)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have already done both. This tutorial only shows forwarding messages. It doesn't show how to instantiate a message object. As for the rest, my code is essentially the same.

Comment: @Knaup In the code sample above, I wrote a simple function **SendSimulationData** to send the message which is initialized with string. Just to make sure that where the issue is relative to construct the message.

Comment: @Knaup Is the issue fixed now?

Comment: My trial expired

Answer (score 0):

If it can help someone, I think you miss `await` send_message.

[Seems the same problem I answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61497052/1665473)